# Consistently assigning electrode nodes in random resistor networks

Tags: resistors, kirchhoffs-laws, network, graph, electrode

In the context of random resistor networks, the general question of interest is often "what is the effective resistance between two arbitrarily chosen nodes?"
But more specifically about the nodes we choose to assign as electrodes, along which we would measure/compute the resistance, are there generally accepted ways or definitions for how to assign the electrodes?

To be more precise, this can be easily relevant as soon as we have two networks (maybe one is a transformed version of the other), and we are interested in comparing the conductivity (or equivalently) the resistance of the two networks. Then depending on how we proceed to choose the electrode-nodes, we will obtain different results and not be able to meaningfully compare the two networks.

To resolve this, one might adopt some of the following, natural looking, definitions, given a network of \$n\$ nodes and \$m\$ edges (resistors, either uniformly valued or according to another known distribution):

- Using the graph diameter nodes: We assign the nodes $i,j$ that are furthest apart as electrodes, i.e., furthest in the sense of the [graph distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) between them.
- We choose the nodes \$i,j\$ randomly and average over \$x\$ such realizations.
- We choose the nodes \$i,j\$ that are exactly a distance \$d\$ apart, and obtain the resistance as a function of graph distance.

Either of these definitions have an arbitrary aspect to them. For example, if we choose the first definition, then the two networks may have very different diameters, and therefore, we'd be comparing resistances at different distances.

My questions are:

1. How does one consistently compare the resistance of two networks either by factoring out effect of the choice of electrodes, or by adopting a generally accepted definition for how to assign the electrode nodes?
2. Is the dependence of resistance on choice of electrode placement a well studied problem? I haven't been able to pinpoint works that directly tackle this aspect of random resistor networks.

Comment: Your question seems to be purely theoretical and I can't imagine why you care. In practice, the choice of the terminals where we measure resistance is dictated by how the network is used in a circuit. You should explain why this matters in the real world.

Comment: This is a question that goes deep down the rabbit hole...

Comment: Problems involving random resistor networks are usually exercises to make the student apply Ohm's Law, series/parallel resistor calculations, and other techniques.  In such cases, you follow the instructions in the question.

Comment: Look up Kelvin current shunt 4 wire method and  differential Amps. Does this hlp?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Indeed the questions are rather theoretical, but that's because I am working at the level of networks of resistors, that is, starting from an arbitrarily shaped samples, whose conductivity is modeled as a resistor network (so a graph with edges having resistors). And in a nutshell, the question is: how do we measure the resistivity of a resistor network?

Comment: Are these uniform or non-uniform resistances? Are the grids finite or infinite?

Comment: @VoltageSpike The grids are finite, and in principle both cases of resistances are of interest, but for the sake of discussions and simplicity let us consider uniformly distributed ones, with 1 Ohm resistors per edge.

Comment: @user929304 How much error can you tolerate in dumbing down the grid model to something simpler? This is the same problem as finding the resistivity between electrodes on the surface of a physical material. If I have three electrodes, I can model them as a sheet of resistors, or I can say there is X material between two electrodes and model it as three resistors (maybe 6) between electrodes based off of the surface conductivity.  The latter model will be less accurate

Comment: @VoltageSpike I hadn't heard of this approach thus far, definitely interested to learn more about it! In terms of gauging the error, hard to say at this point maybe once I understand better the idea behind your approach.

Comment: Perhaps some later works of [Armen Zemanian](http://www.ece.sunysb.edu/~zeman/) will be useful to your research: I have read "*Infinite electrical networks*" and "*Transfiniteness for graphs, electrical networks and random walks*" and perhaps are pertaining to your problem. However, this is more graph theory than electronics enginering.